# Using Unity DI with HostBuilder based .NET Core console application

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, unity-container

With ASP.NET MVC Core it is possible to use the Unity DI packages by loading the appropriate NuGet packages (Unity.Container and Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) and then calling the `UseUnityServiceProvider()` extension method when building the web host in `Program.cs`.  This extension method is based off of the `IWebHostBuilder` interface.  After initializing the host it is possible to access the Unity DI functionality via the .NET Core `GetService` interface and any constructor injection.

I'm working on a console based application that will use `HostBuilder` and the `IHostBuilder` interface.  I've tried reimplementing the registration logic from the `UseUnityServiceProvider()` extension (available here: https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection/blob/master/src/HostingExtension.cs) as part of the `ConfigureServices()` method call against `IHostBuilder`, but the change in service provider does not appear to be visible to downstream DI calls.

Has anyone been successful in getting Unity to work with the Microsoft DI methods in an application created using `HostBuilder`?

***Update*** As requested, here is an example of what I was trying (taken from the Unity source).  Of course, this does not work.  `TestService` has a constructor which should be injected with an object defined in `MyUnityExtension`.  This does not happen.

```cs
private static async Task MainTest()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<MyUnityExtension>();
    var factory = new ServiceProviderFactory(container);

    var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IServiceProviderFactory<IUnityContainer>>(factory));
            services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection>>(factory));

            services.AddHostedService<TestService>();
        });

    await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to achieve with `new UnityContainer().AddNewExtension<MyUnityExtension>()`.

If you just want some registered service to be injected into TestService, why not just use `IUnityContainer.RegisterType<TInterface, TImplementation>()` ?

Here is a working IHost setup in Program.cs (.NET Core 3.1, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting v3.10, Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection v5.11.5):

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IService, MyService>();

    var builder = new HostBuilder()
      .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
      {
          services.AddHostedService<TestService>();
      })
      .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
      {
          logging.AddConsole();
      })
      .UseUnityServiceProvider(container);
    await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

The implementation:

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    public string Name => "My name";
}
```

The TestService:

```
public class TestService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IService service;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public TestService(IService service, ILogger<TestService> logger)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Hello {n}", this.service.Name);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```